# NullPointerException in weblogic's DOMFactoryProperties when parsing an XML document under Tomcat

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, jaxb, weblogic

I'm trying to parse an XML and getting a weirdest `NullPointerException` I've ever seen. Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:399)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.DOMFactoryProperties.<init>(DOMFactoryProperties.java:44)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.DOMFactoryProperties.clone(DOMFactoryProperties.java:114)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryDocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder(RegistryDocumentBuilderFactory.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.createDocument(SAX2DOM.java:324)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.<init>(SAX2DOM.java:84)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.output.TransletOutputHandlerFactory.getSerializationHandler(TransletOutputHandlerFactory.java:187)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:392)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerHandlerImpl.setResult(TransformerHandlerImpl.java:137)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.DomLoader$State.<init>(DomLoader.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.DomLoader.startElement(DomLoader.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ProxyLoader.startElement(ProxyLoader.java:55)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:455)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:433)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:137)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:501)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.WebLogicXMLReader.parse(WebLogicXMLReader.java:133)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryXMLReader.parse(RegistryXMLReader.java:173)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:211)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:184)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:137)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:105)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:584)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:571)
```

Firstly, it only happens when my app is deployed under Tomcat (I'm using weblogic client JAR to connect to external weblogic JMS queues). I could not reproduce it in my tests outside of Tomcat. So I suspect some class loader weirdness or something.

Secondly, I tried to decompile `DOMFactoryProperties` class and here's a constructor that's causing that NPE:

```
public class DOMFactoryProperties
{
  public static String COALESCING = "Coalescing";
  public static String EXPANDENTITYREFERENCES = "ExpandEntityReferences";
  public static String IGNORINGCOMMENTS = "IgnoringComments";
  public static String IGNORINGELEMENTCONTENTWHITESPACE = "IgnoringElementContentWhitespace";
  public static String NAMESPACEAWARE = "Namespaceaware";
  public static String VALIDATING = "Validating";

  public static String SCHEMA = "Schema";

  public static String XINCL = "XIncludeAware";
  private Hashtable factoryProperties;
  private Set facPropertySettingMarks;
  private LinkedHashMap attributes;

  public DOMFactoryProperties()
  {
    this.factoryProperties = new Hashtable();
    this.factoryProperties.put(COALESCING, Boolean.FALSE);
    this.factoryProperties.put(EXPANDENTITYREFERENCES, Boolean.TRUE);
    this.factoryProperties.put(IGNORINGCOMMENTS, Boolean.FALSE);
    this.factoryProperties.put(IGNORINGELEMENTCONTENTWHITESPACE, Boolean.FALSE);
    this.factoryProperties.put(NAMESPACEAWARE, Boolean.FALSE);
    this.factoryProperties.put(VALIDATING, Boolean.FALSE);
    this.factoryProperties.put(XINCL, Boolean.FALSE);

    this.facPropertySettingMarks = new HashSet();

    this.attributes = new LinkedHashMap();
  }

//...
}
```

It's failing on the line `this.factoryProperties.put(COALESCING, Boolean.FALSE);`. The only cause for that could be `null` value in `COALESCING`, but unless some other class is setting that to `null` (as it is `public static` for some reason) from outside I don't see why it can be `null`.

Any idea?

<strike>Is there any way to tell Spring's `Jaxb2Marshaller` to not use XML reader from weblogic?</strike>

**UPDATE**: To make things worse this is not even always reproducible under Tomcat for the same XML. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

**UPDATE2**: Debug shows that `weblogic.xml.jaxp.DOMFactoryProperties.COALESCING` is indeed `null`. But why?

**UPDATE3**: It looks like I can tell which implementation of `SAXParserFactory` to use by setting `javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory` system property to `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl` (platform default). The other question still remains.

Comment: Just put a breakpoint on `COALESCING` variable declaration line to debug access and modification. Once hit with an attempt to modify it to `null`, just read the stack(trace) who called it.

Comment: **BalusC** `DOMFactoryProperties` is from weblogic jar. I was able to decompile it and have look at the source, I was also able to put breakpoint into `Hashtable` and lookup `weblogic.xml.jaxp.DOMFactoryProperties.COALESCING` at that point. I don't think it is possible to debug access and modification of the fields within `DOMFactoryProperties` class though. If you know how please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

We had similar issue one time, also occurring only on Tomcat. As I can see your application uses apache xalan (take a look at the stack trace). Our deep investigation proven that it was caused by inappropriate instantiation of parser factory (as I remember) - probably some strange conflicts between libraries. In our case, adding xalan JAR to the project maven dependencies (it should be available in the `lib` directory of your webapp) solved the problem. I mean - we had to add this dependency explicitly even if project built successfully without it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks A LOT @Piotr De !

I had this exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.output.TransletOutputHandlerFactory.getSerializationHandler(TransletOutputHandlerFactory.java:186)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:453)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:336)
>       at com.xml.fda.sciencepapers.service.impl.DisplayServiceImpl.generateHTML(DisplayServiceImpl.java:114)
>
> ...

Line 114 in DisplayServiceImpl calls the `transform` method of `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`.

I resolved the problem by added the xalan dependency to my pom like this:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/xalan -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

And then got some Serializer class not found Exception, and I added this dependency also:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/serializer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>serializer</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

<del>Here is the link to download the [serializer jar](https://mega.nz/#!MZ5HlKKT!JanihSmmxLE13KyeY-mRADT2p_mcyE7-CpvHBkcy5lg).</del>

<del>Note: I created the lib folder myself, placed it in the resources folder and placed the jars in it.</del>

Edit: Stroke through the above text because I changed the place from where I get the jars from a local folder to the maven repository.